# Restrict aws IAM users to certain EC2 instance types

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I am trying to restrict AWS IAM users to only be able to start `t2.micro` and `t2.small` instances. I've applied the following permissions but I am unable to start any instances with this configuration.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "ec2:InstanceType": [
                        "t2.micro",
                        "t2.small"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I expected this to give me full permission and then deny if the type isn't `t2.micro` or `t2.small`, however it seems to deny everything.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the second `"Resource": "*"` by `"Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"`